# How does stackoverflow set origin: null in http requests

Tags: javascript, http-headers, fetch-api

```js
const url = 'https://nettle-feather-area.glitch.me/'
const opts = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'authorization': 'asdf',
        'x-custom-header': 'asdf',
    },
    method: 'POST',
    credentials:"include",
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'ping' }),
}
fetch(url,opts);
```

[image]

I can see that stackoverflow somehow manages to set origin to null in this request, how does it do that? Would expect origin to be `https://stackoverflow.com` or as commenters have mentioned maybe `stacksnippets.net`. Anything but null!

Is it something to do with iframes?

Comment: Why should it be `stackoverflow.com`? The snippet is executed on `stacksnippets.net`

Comment: yes, it's `stacksnippets.net` - I wonder if it has something to do with it being in an iframe - because stacksnippets not in an iframe don't do that

Comment: yeah okay should be stacksnippets.net anything but null!!

Comment: yep that looks to be it!